# Matlab call a function from a function

Tags: function, matlab

I have two functions:

```
function [] = func_one()
     S.pb = uicontrol('style','push','unit','pix','posit',[20 20 260 30],
                      'string','Print Choices','callback',{@func_two,S});
```

and I have the second function:

```
   function [a] = func_two(varargin)
       a = 'alon';
   end
```

I want `func_one` to return the variable `a` of `func_two`. How can I do that please?

I tried:

```
 function [a] = func_one()
```

But I guess I have to do something with 'callback',{@func_two,S})

Thank you all!

Comment: @Memming, I changed my question. if you can, please look at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, as you say, you want `func_one` to return the value `a` in `func_two` then the easiest way to do this without using a callback is:

```
function [a] = func_one()
     S.pb = uicontrol('style','push','unit','pix','posit',[20 20 260 30],
                      'string','Print Choices');

     a = func_two()
```

The above will allow you to say run `a=func_one` and `a` will be the string `'alon'`.

If you really really want `func_two()` to be a callback of your pushbutton, and you want `a='alon'` to be assigned in the workspace of `func_one` (the function that calls `func_two`) then put this in `func_two`

```
assignin('caller','a',a)
```

And if neither is what you want, then maybe you can indicate why you want `func_one` to return what `func_two` returns - like the exact interaction you are hoping to have with your GUI and how it differs from what you're actually experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

If you are designing a GUI programmatically, I suggest you use nested functions to [share data](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-38068.html#f0-50984). Example:

```
function IncrementExample()
    x = 0;
    uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'String','(0)', ...
        'Callback',@callback);

    function callback(o,e)
        %# you can access the variable x in here
        x = x + 1;

        %# update button text
        set(o, 'String',sprintf('(%d)',x))
        drawnow
    end
end
```

[image]